# Navigation bar moves when AdMob Interstital showed

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, admob, interstitial

When I show Interstital Ad status bar fades away and Navigation Bar moves up. All content under navigation bar moves up to. When I close the ad everything moves down. It looks really strange and glitchy.

I'm using Navigation Controller in storyboard with `Show Navigation Bar` property on.

Code to show Interstital Ad in `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
[self.interstitialAd presentFromRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
```

Basically, I need everything to stay in place without moving when I present Interstital Ad.

Comment: Try Below: 
`UINavigationController *aNavCntrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.interstitialAd];
[aNavCntrl presentFromRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];`

Comment: @SharmaVishal, `self.interstitialAd` is `GADInterstitial` not `ViewController`. Also `UINavigationController` has no `presentFromRootViewController` method. Maybe you want to correct your comment?

Comment: Yes, Pardon. It was thought only :)

Comment: Are you using Storyboard, and laying your views using top and bottom layout guides?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect, yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try the following:

In the StoryBoard:

1. Add a UIVisualEffectView with Blur over your existing view hierarchy
   (or even outside of it)
2. Load the AdMob into another new view on top of the blurred one or
   within the view above
3. Manage the presentation from your view controller by the loading of
   the ad within a custom view
4. Use auto layout animation to present the custom view on screen
       (maybe as a popover )

OR

Check out the UICatalog Sample from Apple. They provide an example of presenting a search display controller over the navigation bar.

```
import UIKit

class SearchPresentOverNavigationBarViewController: SearchControllerBaseViewController {
    // MARK: Properties

    // `searchController` is set when the search button is clicked.
    var searchController: UISearchController!

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func searchButtonClicked(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Create the search results view controller and use it for the UISearchController.
        let searchResultsController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SearchResultsViewController.StoryboardConstants.identifier) as SearchResultsViewController

        // Create the search controller and make it perform the results updating.
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        // Present the view controller.
        presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```